# Missing one required positional argument? Any idea why?

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

I am trying the below problem:

> Implement a CardHand class that supports a person arranging a group of
>   cards in his or her hand. The simulator should represent the sequence
>   of cards using a single positional list ADT so that cards of the same
>   suit are kept together. Implement this strategy by means of four
>   “fingers” into the hand, one for each of the suits of hearts, clubs,
>   spades, and diamonds, so that adding a new card to the person’s hand
>   or playing a correct card from the hand can be done in constant time.
>   The class should support the following methods:
>
> - add card(r, s): Add a new card with rank r and suit s to the hand.
> - play(s): Remove and return a card of suit s from the player’s hand; if there is no card of suit s, then remove and return an arbitrary
>     card from the hand.
> - iter (): Iterate through all cards currently in the hand.
> - all of suit(s): Iterate through all cards of suit s that are currently in the hand.

```
class CardHand:
"""Class representing a hand of cards"""

    class _Card:
        """Class representing a single card"""
        suits = ['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades']
        ranks= ['Ace','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

        def __init__(self,suit,rank):
            self._suit = suit
            self._rank = rank

        def __str__(self):
            return self._rank + ' ' + self._suit


    def __init__(self):
        self._hand = PositionalList()
        self._size = 0

    def _validate(self,s,r):
        card = self._Card(s,r)
        if not card._suit in suits:
            raise ValueError("Such card doesn't exist")
        if not card._rank in ranks:
            raise ValueError("Invalid card value")
        return card

    def add_card(self,s,r):
            return  self._hand.add_first(self._Card(s,r))

print(CardHand.add_card('s', '4'))
```

I've got the code for the Positional list and its base but it's too much lines to read, so i won't post it. I've been using the same Positional list for other tasks and it's been working. Just asking if you can see why this piece of code would throw this error:

> "Missing one required positional argument "r".

Comment: Do you have a class within a class?

Comment: You're calling the class, not an instance...
CardHand.add_card('s', '4')

Comment: Yes, i' ve been told thank you anyway. Common knowledge  I suppose but caused me a lot of headache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling an *instance method* as a *static method*. Instead of

```
CardHand.add_card('s', '4')
```

you should do

```
ch = CardHand()
ch.add_card('s', '4')
```

---

Here's why: the argument `self` in

```
def add_card(self, s, r):
```

refers to *the instance on which `add_card()` is being called* - in my latter example above, `ch` is being passed into the method as `self`, invisibly. In fact, the following two are equivalent:

```
ch.add_card('s', '4')
CardHand.add_card(ch, 's', '4')
```

So when you do `CardHand('s', '4')`, you're not calling it on an *instance*, you're calling it on *the class itself*. So, naturally, python gets confused and says "where's that third argument I'm supposed to be seeing?", and that's causing your error.

---

Incidentally, if you *do* want to make a static method - one that can be called on the class itself, and not on an instance of the class (and therefore, without a `self` parameter), you can do so using a decorator:

```
@staticmethod
def some_method(a, b):
    ...
```

Alternatively, it's also possible to have a *class method*, which is like an instance method but takes *the type of class* as an argument instead of *an instance of the class*:

```
@classmethod
def some_method(cls, a, b):
    ...
```

The former is useful occasionally. The latter is only really relevant when you're dealing with polymorphism and inheritance.